# Does this code follow Observer pattern?

Tags: rust, observer-pattern

I was trying to apply observer pattern to Rust. As in other GC languages such as JS or Java, I wanted to send references to the data in `Observable` in an event to `Observer`. But the compiler kept on giving me headache because of the borrow checker. So because of that I learned of using `Rc` but it did not let me mutate the value in `Observable` then I used a `RefCell` for internal mutability which worked as I wanted. Hoorah I said. But then I realised the `Rc` causes a single location to be referred from different places which made the event system on the `Observer` obsolete. So after removing the event method from `Observer`, I got:

```
struct Observable<T: Clone> {
    value: Rc<RefCell<T>>
}

impl<T: Clone> Observable<T> {
    fn new(value: T) -> Observable<T> {
        Observable {
            value: Rc::new(RefCell::new(value))
        }
    }

    fn set_value(&mut self, value: T) {
        *self.value.borrow_mut() = value;
    }

    fn register(&mut self) -> Observer<T> {
        Observer::new(self.value.clone())
    }
}

struct Observer<T: Clone> {
    value: Rc<RefCell<T>>
}

impl<T: Clone> Observer<T> {
    fn new(value: Rc<RefCell<T>>) -> Observer<T> {
        Observer {
            value
        }
    }

    fn value(&self) -> T {
        (*self.value.borrow()).clone()
    }
}
```

[Link to Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=0d48d04e3ef38151ce570e318d60ae3d&version=stable)

So does the above given code represent an Observer Pattern from a technical point of view? Because otherwise it works for me. But just wanted to know what constitutes an Observer Pattern?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So does the above given code represent an Observer Pattern from a
>   technical point of view?

**NO**

> But just wanted to know what constitutes an Observer Pattern?

I have updated your code to simulate the Observer Pattern.

```
#[allow(unused_variables)]
pub trait Events {
    fn on_value(&self, value: &str) {}
}
struct Observable {
    value: String,
    observers: Vec<Box<Events>>,
}

impl Observable {
    fn new(value: &str) -> Observable {
        Observable {
            value: value.to_owned(),
            observers: Vec::new(),
        }
    }

    fn set_value(&mut self, value: &str) {
        self.value = value.to_owned();
        // send event to observers
        for observer in &self.observers {
            observer.on_value(value);
        }
    }

    fn register<E: Events + 'static>(&mut self, observer: E) {
        self.observers.push(Box::new(observer));
    }
}

struct Observer;

impl Events for Observer {
    fn on_value(&self, value: &str) {
        println!("received value: {:?}", value);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut observable = Observable::new("initial value");
    observable.register(Observer);
    observable.set_value("updated value");
}
```

The **Observable** is the subject and it maintains a list of **observers**.
When an new value is set, the Observable notifies the observers.

[Link to playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=d29f04553301ccaa0c44d9c7b69a7287&version=stable)

[Blog post about the Observer Pattern in Rust](http://mattgathu.github.io/simple-events-hook-rust/)

Answer (score 1):

No, it does not represent the observer pattern.

From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern)

> The observer pattern is a software design pattern in which an object, called the subject, maintains a list of its dependents, called observers, and notifies them automatically of any state changes, usually by calling one of their methods.

What's missing from your implementation is that the observers are not being notified when the observable changes.